# Find the column name which has the latest date for each row - idxmax returning TypeError with datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following table:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-02-15 00:00:00 | 0 | 2022-03-46 00:00:00 |
| 2022-04-23 00:00:00 | 2021-01-10 00:00:00 | 0 |

I would like to get a resulting column that returns the column name of the latest date per row and ignore all empty rows (this is part of a bigger dataset so I can't dropna). So as follows:

| A | B | C | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2022-02-15 00:00:00 | 0 | 2022-03-46 00:00:00 | C |
| 2022-04-23 00:00:00 | 2021-01-10 00:00:00 | 0 | A |

I converted the columns to datetime and tried using:

```
df['Result'] = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

But this only resulted in the following error

```
TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype
```

Comment: Convert first your dates to datetime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have datetime type.

If you don't want to alter the dataframe, you can do it on the fly:

```
df['Result'] = df.apply(pd_to_datetime).idxmax(axis=1).mask(df.eq(0).all(1), 0)
```